# Simple Navigation not shown nested items using bootstrap on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to nested my menu items by it can not show.

Gist https://gist.github.com/poc7667/7019484

it should show the two net.item in my menu. but it didn't.

I guess the problem is due to the I have to do some css in the output html, but how to?

```
primary.item :urltests, 'Network/Documentation', root_path  do |net_docs|

  net_docs.item :net, "URL Command", welcome_af_form_path do |net|        
    net.item :vvtk, "VIVOTEK", urltests_path
    net.item :sony, "SONY", sony_url_command_automation_tests_path
  end

  # net_docs.item :div, "Translate Strings", :class => 'dropdown-header'
  # net_docs.item :div, "divider" , :class => 'divider'
  # net_docs.item :trans_db, 'Firmware', translates_path
end
```

here the look

[image]

Here are my bundle list

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.12)
  * actionpack (3.2.12)
  * activemodel (3.2.12)
  * activerecord (3.2.12)
  * activeresource (3.2.12)
  * activesupport (3.2.12)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * atomic (1.1.14)
  * awesome_print (1.1.0)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
  * bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
  * builder (3.0.4)
  * bundler (1.3.5)
  * cancan (1.6.10)
  * carrierwave (0.9.0)
  * celluloid (0.15.1)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
  * connection_pool (1.1.0)
  * devise (3.1.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.0.1)
  * haml (4.0.3)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * hirb (0.7.1)
  * hirb-unicode (0.0.5)
  * i18n (0.6.5)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-datatables-rails (1.11.2 494f752)
  * jquery-rails (3.0.4)
  * jquery-ui-rails (4.0.4)
  * json (1.8.0)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.25)
  * mini_portile (0.5.1)
  * multi_json (1.8.0)
  * nokogiri (1.6.0)
  * orm_adapter (0.4.0)
  * pg (0.17.0)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * quiet_assets (1.0.2)
  * rack (1.4.5)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.3)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (3.2.12)
  * railties (3.2.12)
  * rake (10.1.0)
  * rdoc (3.12.2)
  * redis (3.0.4)
  * redis-namespace (1.3.1)
  * rest-client (1.6.7)
  * sass (3.2.10)
  * sass-rails (3.2.6)
  * sequel (3.20.0)
  * sidekiq (2.14.0)
  * simple-navigation (3.11.0)
  * simple-navigation-bootstrap (1.0.0)
  * sinatra (1.0)
  * sprockets (2.2.2)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.8)
  * taps (0.3.24)
  * thor (0.18.1)
  * thread_safe (0.1.3)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * timers (1.1.0)
  * tinymce-rails (4.0.2)
  * tlsmail (0.0.1)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8 40ffd56)
  * tzinfo (0.3.37)
  * uglifier (2.2.1)
  * unicode-display_width (0.1.1)
  * warden (1.2.3)
  * will_paginate (3.0.4)
```

OUTPUT HTML

```
 <div class='navbar'>
          <div class='navbar-inner'>
            <div id='top_navi'><ul class="nav"><li id="remotefocus"><a href="/">Image</a></li><li class="active dropdown" id="urltests"><a href="/" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Network/Documentation <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class="active dropdown" id="network"><a href="/welcome/af_form" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">URL Command <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="tabs span16 dropdown-menu"><li class="active simple-navigation-active-leaf" id="vvtk"><a href="/urltests" class="active">VIVOTEK</a></li><li id="sony"><a href="/sony_url_command_automation_tests">SONY</a></li></ul></li><li id="trans_db"><a href="/translates">Firmware</a></li></ul></li><li id="translate"><a href="/">Translate String</a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the complete navigation tree to be rendered all the time (independent of the current URL), you need to call render_navigation with the expand_all option set to true:

```
render_navigation :expand_all => true, ...
```

If you don't pass this option, simple-navigation usually only renders the subnavigation of the active primary navigation item (depending on the current URL).

Comment: did your try the :expand_all option as described above?

Comment: Oh it didn't work. I Can see the submenus in DOM. But not show in page

Comment: If you can see it in the DOM, but not on the page, make sure they're visible. Maybe you have a CSS rule that hides them?

Answer (score 0):

@poc.
As I understood from your issue, you have problem with 'submenu'.
There is class `dropdown-submenu` in [Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns), which should be used like following:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that gem `simple-navigation-bootstrap`, which you use to create Bootstrap menu, does not generate that class.

I've just created another gem [`simple_navigation_renderers`](https://github.com/ShPakvel/simple_navigation_renderers) to solve that problem and to provide easy way to create Bootstrap 'headers' and 'dividers'. There is possibility to add icons of any kind (library) as well. And, actually, there are two renderers: for Bootstrap 2 and for Bootstrap 3. ;)
Try it. I think it will help you. And I hope you will enjoy it.

Comment: The gem looks promising. Should I add it to the simple-navigation wiki?

Comment: Sure, Andi. I like the idea. If you have any improvement idea or suggestions, I am all ears.

Comment: Again, @poc, from your gist it is clear that you have nested `dropdown-menu` wrapped up with `dropdown`. But it is correct only for first level `dropdown-menu`. For nested `dropdown-menu` there is special class `dropdown-submenu` in [Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns), as I mentioned above. You should use it (`dropdown-submenu`), instead of `dropdown`, for **nested** `dropdown-menu`. In Bootstrap 3 there is no nested `dropdown-menu`, but you can create it yourself.